# How do I multiple second batch query (skip) on MongoDB if there's no numeric row index

Tags: database, mongodb, skip, chunks

Usually I did this

`db.flat_transaction.find({},{"customer_id": 1,"item": 1, "_id":0}).limit(3000000)`

But, I want to query the `3000001-6000000` entry , `6000001-9000000`entry, etc.

How suppose I do this?

Comment: [`skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)?

Comment: Ok, I'm new on mongoDB, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MongoDB [Skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)

```
db.flat_transaction.find({},{"customer_id": 1,"item": 1, "_id":0}).skip(3000000).limit(3000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could cursor.skip() be something you could use?

It allows you to skip x-number of elements before MongoDB starts to return results

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/